# WordPress: Adding Theme Support

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add the "Custom-Background" theme hook for a WordPress site.

In my functions file, the one for the theme folder, I added

```
add_theme_support( 'Custom Background', array (
    'background-color' => '#000000',
    'background-size' => 'cover'
) );
```

It seems to work because going into the WordPress Dashboard -> Appearances -> Background, I can add an image and have it shown in the Customizer space. But when I actually go to the page itself, it shows me a blank white background.

Is there an additional code I need to add to my '.php' files? There was a similar post previously here:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259315/custom-background-image-not-showing-up

But I believe this does not work anymore, or maybe I'm doing my process wrong.

Comment: Hey @steve have you tried this add_theme_support( 'custom-background' ); as well?

Comment: Hi, that's the first thing I did to add the menu. But I know my mistake and I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [codex sample](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds) you need this format

```
$args = array(
    'default-image' => 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg',
    'default-size' => 'cover',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args );
```

Comment: use this for your case 'default-color'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying. I found out what the issue was with my code. It wasn't that my code was in an incorrect form, but I had forgotten to put a

```
<body <?php body_class();?>>
```

wherever I put my  tag in.